# How prevalent is the usage of the word prudent among native english speakers

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I'm not certain if this is the appropriate place to inquire, but I have a question about the English language: I recently learned the word "prudent" and its meaning. However, I'm curious about how common this word is in the everyday vocabulary of native English speakers. As a non-native speaker, I want to ensure that the words I learn are well-understood and commonly used in English-speaking countries like the United States, the United Kingdom, and Australia. Otherwise, knowing them won't be very beneficial.

Comment: [Centuries ago,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prudent%2Ccareful%2Ccautious&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) ***prudent*** was actually more common than ***careful***. ***Cautious*** is another closely-related term, but I'd expect almost *every* native Anglophone today to know all 3 words, even if some people might never actually *use* one or two of them in their own speech. But "How common is this word?" is an inherently subjective question, so I think it's an Off Topic "matter of opinion".

Comment: ...note that Google Books / NGrams give you *some* idea of relative prevalence, but you need to bear in mind 99.99% of all language output from most native Anglophones is ***spoken***, which may not be accurately reflected in ***written, published*** texts.

Comment: *Prudent* would be understood nearly universally, in the US anyway.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Indeed, though as a high school teacher, I would guess that half of the next generation would have only a vague idea of what it means.

Comment: *prudent* is a more formal than, say, careful. The word **prudence** is used in accounting; it is a principle of accounting. There is a list somewhere re common words in English. This word is probably not among them. But most people with at least a high school education would probably understand it.

Comment: I use it quite often. It is prudent to check that your ticket is valid before boarding a train, or that your tyres are properly inflated before driving a long way at high speeds.

Comment: Prudent is probably considered by some to be quite a formal word today.  I'd say that most native English speakers will know it, however in everyday speech/conversation it's probably not as common as some of its synonyms, such as wise, careful, reasonable, sensible.

Comment: *Prudence* has a long history in western philosophical tradition. People who have only finished secondary school are not likely to use it but anyone who has attended a four-year college or university would not consider it or **prudent** an usual word, not if they have been required to take a basic introductory course in western philosophy.

Comment: @Lambie - in literature, it's the name of a well-known kitten, and perhaps related, my mother was quite pally with the man from the Prudential [Insurance company].

Comment: There is also the first name for a woman: Prudence. No longer much used but prevalent from the 19th c. back.

Answer (score 3):

Not very common.  For example Cambridge marks "Careful" as "A2" (an essential word learned at elementary level, necessary for a learner to know to understand routine situations). Other lists place it as A1 (basic). "Cautious" is B2- upper intermediate (necessary to discuss a range of abstract concepts in a fairly sophisticated way). It doesn't mark "Prudent" with a level, indicating it is an "advanced word" that students may learn when developing fluency in the language.

On the other hand, nearly all educated native speakers of English would understand the word "prudent", and most would be able to use it.

Many dictionaries will indicate how common a word is.  Cambridge, for example, uses A1-B2 markings for the most common words.  It will also include usage markers such as "slang", "obsolete" or "technical" for words that are not widely used today. "Prudent" is not technical, obsolete or slang.

Answer (score 0):

Children's media doesn't shy away from using "prudent"/"prudence" and neither should you:

[image: The Virtue of Prudence]

As for raw numbers, this is what I get from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

- PRUDENT: 3812 (3.84 per million words)
- PRUDENCE: 2417 (2.43 per million words)